# how to load data without page refresh using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Here is my code for loading data

```
$(document).ready(function() {         
    $.get('get-answers.php', { 
        project_question_id: <?=$project_question_id?>,
        project_id: <?=$project_id?>
    }, function(data) {
        $('#dispaly-answers').append(data);
    });  
});
```

This code  retrieves data from database and working fine. But problem here is that if I add new data on the database, this data doesn't show up without page refresh. 
So I don’t want to refresh the page to get the data. It should be displayed once new data added to database. 
Any suggestions on this issue? 
P.S : I also tried .ajax(), didn’t work.

Here is my $.ajax() request
$(document).ready(function() {

```
 $.ajax( {
type: "GET",                 
url: "get-answers.php",                 
data: { project_question_id: <?=$project_question_id?>,
        project_id: <?=$project_id?>
        },
cache: false,                  

  success: function(data) {   
  $('#dispaly-answers').append(data);                      

           },// success                 

    })// ajax   

});
```

Does the same as $.get()

Comment: @AlanMachado - He is using ajax in the above code.

Comment: `Console.log(data)` if he retrieves the data.

Comment: Assuming everything is working as it should when saving the data, it sounds like you may need to use a full `$.ajax()` request and set `cache:  false`.

Comment: A few points: (1) Typically people do not just load a page and then wait for it to update ... they usually perform certain actions on the page once the page loads. The goal of a developer is to leverage those user actions to update the page where necessary. **To what user action do you want an AJAX call to be made to fetch fresh data?** (2). An AJAX call that loads data at DOM ready is not really of much use. **That data could be loaded normally; there's no advantage to loading it with AJAX.**

Comment: @PeterKA I disagree with your first point. Pages that dynamically update independent of user action are quite common: see the "most recent reviews" tiles on the SO review page, for example http://stackoverflow.com/review .

Comment: Rory McCrossan, see the update, I just added $.ajax() request. It doesn't work too

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to refresh the page data without refreshing the page, you can put your code in an interval timer and let it auto refresh every x seconds, like below.

```
setInterval(getAnswer(), 1000);
```

note: `setInterval` fires again and again until you clear it, while `setTimeout` only fires once.

Answer (score 0):

The Ajax-Function get only called once: In the moment the document is ready (fully loaded). You have to use setTimeout to create a timer, which calls the function every minute or whatever you want. Like this:

```
function getData() {
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        $.get('get-answers.php', { 
             project_question_id: <?=$project_question_id?>,
             project_id: <?=$project_id?>
        }, function(data) {
            $('#dispaly-answers').append(data);
            getData();
        });  
    }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: Your code is logical, but it doesn't work too. I tried with  setTimeout  method with different way. It worked but it constantly gets the whole data  that is not got for server. So I stopped this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final approach
 $(document).ready(function() {

```
     setInterval(function(){ 
        $.ajax( {
              type: "GET",                 
               url: "get-answers.php",                 
                 data: { project_question_id: <?=$project_question_id?>,
                         project_id: <?=$project_id?>
                       },
                 cache: false,                   

               success: function(data) {   
                 $('#dispaly-answers').html(data);                      

               },// success                

        })// ajax
    }, 1000);


});
```

Without creating and calling function getData(), this code working fine. Also I have changed .append(data) to .html(data).

But still I'm not happy with my code because it is constantly retrieving data from database that makes data server busy.

Whatever I wanted to tasks has to be done and it is done.

Answer (score 0):

Try this you just need to replace this file retrieve_query.php and this id query-div with yours.

```
setInterval(function(){ 
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            $('#query-div').html(this.responseText);
          }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","retrieve_query.php",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    },1000);
```